# Need to find exact order of elements within <span> and </span>

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am looking for some help.  In reference to the following screenshot of the partial DOM object (for security, I have blocked the actual URL)

- There are two "span" sections
- In the first one, the Class precedes the text (rendering "< Previous")
- In the second one, the Class follows the text (rendering "Next >")

[image]

Question:  I want to make sure that in the first case, Class *precedes* the text and in the second case, Class *follows* the text. Am I being too ambitious? :)

A problem was reported in my product that the "< Previous" was showing up as "Previous<".  It is fixed and at this point, I am developing automated test for it.  I want to ensure that this order is preserved from this point on in the code.

Comment: What code are you using to get the text?

Comment: I am not even sure how to access the child elements of SPAN.

Comment: What have you tried and how doesn't it work? You should need any special technique to get those elements based on what I can see of what you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it would work for your example. To confirm the order like your first example, try

```
if (spanElement.getAttribute("innerHTML").endsWith(" Previous")) {
    // do what you want
};
```

For your second example,

```
if (spanElement.getAttribute("innerHTML").startsWith("Next ")) {
    // do what you want
};
```

Although this may not be strong enough to ensure what you want I'm not sure.

Comment: I think the issue is for `previous` the OP wants to ensure the HTML hierarchy is `//span/i<previous_text>` and for `next` its `//span<next_text>/i`....basically the position of the `i` element, before and after the text.  That's how I read it anyway. It's a weird test

Comment: I think I understood the same thing... but the `<text>` part and `i` element, I think, are "siblings" if you will even though the `<text>` part is not an element. And because of that I don't think you can verify the HTML structure without somehow parsing through the whole innerHTML of the span, and this seemed like the simplest way to do so adequetely.

Comment: Your understanding is correct...and C. Peck, your solution worked.  Thanks for your quick help.